# Bower install command errors

Tags: javascript, npm, bower

Hi i cant use bower install command, it always tries to resolve ngTour and i cant figure out what is happening!
Here is a screenshot of my CMD output.

[image: Screenshot of CMD running bower install]

Environment

OS: Win 10 Pro

npm: 2.11.3

Bower: 1.7.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Url for the repo is `https://github.com/hanselsen/ngTour.git` not `https://github.com/hanselsen/ngTour-ng-route.git` so change it on your `bower.json` by: `bower install 'https://github.com/hanselsen/ngTour.git'`. You might want to remove it from that file before.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, i found it myself in a hard way :)
I had to delete all the dependencies and resolutions in bower.json